# A função de "lá", na expressão "desculpa lá"

Tags: gramática, expressões, expressões-idiomáticas, origem

As vezes ouço "desculpa lá", o que faz a palavrinha "lá"? É usada para reforçar "desculpa" (uma desculpa mais intensa), ou só para encher, como *filler*? Ou trata-se simplesmente duma expressão idiomática?

Ou seria "lá" usado no sentido "então"? 
Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na minha sensibilidade, em *desculpa lá*, o *lá* é sobretudo um expletivo (um *filler*), que sem acrescentar significado arredonda e completa a frase. O mais importante num pedido de desculpas—o que o torna num pedido sentido, ou numa mera formalidade, ou até num 'pedido' desdenhoso que não é pedido—é a entoação. Mas o *lá* contribui para suavizar o imperativo, tornando-o mais num pedido e não numa ordem. Sem o *lá*, um *desculpa* ou *desculpa-me* teria de ser dito com especial sentimento para não parecer brusco. Isto pertence à linguagem informal: para um pedido de desculpas mais sério, seria qualquer coisa como *peço imensa desculpa*.

Nós usamos este *lá* não só com *desculpa* mas com outros imperativos. Novamente me parece que quase sempre o *lá* é sobretudo um expletivo, que normalmente contribui para suavizar o imperativo. Mas mais uma vez, o tom de voz é o mais importante neste aspeto. O dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa atribui-lhe um valor enfático, o que me parece uma explicação demasiado curta:

> **lá** (1) [...] **II.** Usa-se [...] **6.** Com valor de ênfase, a seguir a um pedido ou uma ordem. *Vá lá! Deixe lá! Olhe lá, não caia. «Cala-te lá malandro!—gritava-lhe o homem.—Anda lá na minha frente!»* (M. da Fonseca, *Cerromaior*). *«Fique lá com o troco.»*  (D. Mourão-Ferreira, *Gaivotas em Terra*). *Deixa-o lá, disse a sua mãe quase com doçura.»* (D. Mourão-Ferreira, *Gaivotas em Terra*).

Comment: Em pt-BR os usos mais comuns são em "vá lá" (no sentido de "vá lá que seja" ou "dessa vez passa"), "vê lá" ou "vê lá, hein" (como uma advertência) e "olha lá" (também como um aviso)  Mas também já ouvi "desculpa lá" algumas vezes.  Boa resposta +1.

Comment: @Centaurus Em Portugal entre amigos, o *lá* é praticamente obrigatório com o *desculpa*. O dicionário da Academia tem dez aceções só deste *lá* expletivo, enfático, expressivo.

Comment: @Centaurus Em *vê lá, heim* é **mesmo** obrigatório. Se eu dissesse *vê, heim* peguntavam-me *vejo em quê?* ou *quem é o "em"?*

Comment: Em ptBR o uso de "lá" é obrigatório em todos aqueles que mencionei acima.  "Vá!", "Olha!" e "Vê!" sem o "lá" não transmitem aquilo que se deseja.

Comment: Vê lá é uma redução de "Veja lá o que vai fazer!" ou "Vê lá o que vai fazer!", onde acredito que lá signifique o lugar e o momento em que vai acontecer e que se toma a decisão, como em Olha lá. Vá lá ou Deixa pra lá, esse lá justamente empurra pra longe o problema, não parece o mesmo caso dos anteriores.